# Theme options missing from edit page

Tags: block-editor, wp-editor

I'm still somewhat new to WP, so I apologize if this is an obvious thing I'm missing.

When I click to edit or create a page, I seem to remember that I would get a page with all sorts of options, and boxes, kind of like the one I'm typing in right now. I'd also have the theme options below that box.

I haven't done much in WP in a while, but I was getting back into it today and, when I create or edit a page, all I see is this one small box in the middle of a large empty page, for the title. Then I get a similar box beneath it (not even a border on the box, or formatting toolbar, etc) for some content.

Where did the rest of the stuff go? I'm totally lost! I also need to get to those options so I can disable the sidebar, make the page go full width, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Not all themes have the same options or functionality, if you're using a different theme that you did previously, you won't necessarily have the same options.

Comment: I hear that. But the whole section is missing. I also am using the same theme as in a tutorial I'm watching. He has the section and I don't. I also tried to look in the theme's inherent settings and can't find all the ones he mentions, so it makes me wonder if it's a versioning thing both on WP and the theme.